# How do I go deeper into JSON?

Tags: apex, json

I'm following along with the code in [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BdRSQA0) and I want to know how I would go a level deeper into JSON output to obtain the values for the keys that I need:

```
Map<String, Object> npiResults = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
// Cast the values in the 'results' key as a list
List<Object> allresults =(List<Object>)npiResults.get('results');
```

Would it be something like this?

```
List<Object> allresults =(List<Object>)npiResults.get('results').get('whatevernestedkeyineed');
```

XML has something called "dot notation" and I want to know what the equivalent would be for JSON.

Comment: Your post would be dramatically improved if you **[edit]** it to include a sample payload.

Answer (score 2):

The result from get will always be an object, so you'd have to cast multiple times:

```
List<Object> allresults =(List<Object>)npiResults.get('results');
for(Object value: allresults) {
    Object itemValue = ((Map<String, Object>)value).get('whatevernestedkeyineed');
    // etc...
```

Using JSON.deserializedUntyped requires a lot of casting, but is frequently better when you have either keys you can't put in to classes or variable/unpredictable structures.

When possible, though, consider using JSON.deserialize for better performance and less casting needed.

Comment: I see. Yea, I have no clue how to put keys into classes  and tie that all together. Has someone written a book on this subject?

Comment: @murkywaters Have you looked in to json2apex?

Comment: Hi SFDCFox, I have but I don't know how the JSON2Apex output would fit in with my existing .axpc file. I don't quite fully understand how to tie a top class to another in different files.

Comment: @murkywaters as long as the class is `public`, you can access that class from any other class in your code. Just reference it by name. For example, given `public class Wrapper { ... }`, in another class, you can write `Wrapper w = new Wrapper();` The same is true for the generated JSON2Apex code. Make it a class of its own, then reference it in your own code.